# How can I check JavaScript code for syntax errors ONLY from the command line?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, jslint, jshint

JavaScript programs can be checked for errors in IDEs or using [online web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279226/how-to-check-client-side-javascript-code-for-errors) but I'm looking for a way to detect syntax errors *alone*.

I've tried JSLint and JSHint and looked at their options but I haven't been able to find a combination that would exclude warnings and [just shows the syntax errors](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1533).

How do I check JavaScript code *for syntax errors only* from the command line?

Comment: Use the [command line version of JSLint](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jslint) then.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Than set up the validation rules to the way you want! http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options

Comment: @epascarello: Do you know which combination of JSLint options will only output syntax errors?

Comment: Here is the [meta discussion about whether this question should be re-opened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222790/request-to-reopen-so-question-on-javascript-error-detection).

Comment: Dan, perhaps you could rephrase your question to something like "How to show syntax errors only **with JSHint** (and/or JSLint)", then it wouldn't look so much like a question "asking to recommend or find a tool".

Comment: @RandomSeed: As part of the research I've done on the question, I've looked at the options for JSLint and JSHint and it doesn't seem possible to only show errors. I even [asked the author of JSHint on GitHub](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1533) for such an option (no answer).

Comment: If I am remembering correctly, you can use the Google Closure Compiler to check for syntax errors.

Comment: If you know JavaScript well, you can simply edit/fork [JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js) and make it do what you want. Not as daunting as it sounds. The code is *very* clean. This question has been asked before iirc; you might find your errors-only JSLint project is pretty popular.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is to enable jshint's `--verbose` option, which shows the error or warning code (e.g. `E020` for `Expected '}' to match '{'` or `W110` for `Mixed double and single quotes`), then grep for errors only:

```
jshint --verbose test.js | grep -E E[0-9]+.$
```

Comment: If there are too many warnings and errors though you end up getting a "too many errors, quitting" message. You need to set a config file option such as maxerr:10000 to avoid this, which is not ideal.

Comment: @mynameistechno, you could also add --maxerr 10000 when calling it from the command line, as the answer seems to already imply.

Comment: jshint 2.9.4 doesn't seem to take a "--maxerr" argument - was it removed?

Answer (score 32):

I use [`acorn`](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/acorn/):

```
$ acorn --silent tests/files/js-error.js; echo $?
Unexpected token (1:14)
1

$ acorn --silent tests/files/js-ok.js; echo $?
0
```

Install via: `npm -g install acorn`.

Comment: `acorn` does not seen to work for me: `Error: Cannot find module './_acorn.js'`

Comment: Also installable in debian with `apt install node-acorn`

Answer (score 5):

JSHint does what you want. http://www.jshint.com/

You can configure which warnings or errors to show.

An example:

```
$ jshint myfile.js
myfile.js: line 10, col 39, Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.

1 error
```

Comment: How do I configure it to show *only* syntax errors, not warnings?

Comment: currently it's not possible to disable all warnings in jshint. You have to do it one by one in a config file :/

Comment: On Mac OSX, this can be installed using: npm install -g jshint

Answer (score 4):

Any JavaScript parser should do, `acorn` mentioned by @cweise is nice because it is fast and has a `--silent` switch.

You could also use `esvalidate` from the npm `esprima` package: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2012/10/javascript-validator-with-esprima.html

```
$ npm install -g esprima
$ esvalidate js-file-with-errors.js 
js-file-with-errors.js:1: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use node's built-in syntax checking option:

```
node --check filename.js
```

Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_c_check

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for a Continuous Integration scenario.

1- Checks all the JavaScript files with exclude folder, subfolder and file features.

2- Exit if there is an error.

```
esvalidate --version || npm install -g esprima;
find ./ -not \( -path ./exclude_folder_1 -prune \) -not \( -path ./exclude/sub_folder -prune \) -not \( -path ./exclude/sub_folder_2 -prune \) ! -name exclude_specified_file.js  -name \*.js -exec esvalidate '{}' \; | grep -v "No syntax errors detected" && echo "Javascript Syntax error(s) detected" && exit 1;
```